# How to add history item from Redmine plugin

Tags: plugins, history, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am trying to write a plugin for Redmine. The plugin will allow users to create Code Review Requests.

When the user creates / updates / deletes a request I want to add the event to history.

Anyone here familiar with creating a Journal object and attaching it to an issue?

I tried doing (using the console)

```
is = Issue.find(1234)
jr = Journal.new(:journalized => is)
jr.save
```

However jr.save returns false.

Please let me know what would be a correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I found the answer. I just added notes to the existing journal.
`code`
    issue = @review.issue
    issue.journals << Journal.new(:journalized => issue, :notes => "Created review request for #{@review.group.lastname}", :user_id => @review.user.id)
`code`

Comment: then do you make `issue.save`?

Comment: @jperelli No I did not have to call save on the issue model instance. I am using Redmine1.3.3

Answer (score 2):

To create issue history line on behalf of user(as a comment):

*writing line by line, to show howto. You can combine in 1 line all this code*

```
issue = Issue.find(1234)
user = User.current
journal = issue.init_journal(user, 'My text for history line')
journal.save
```